# codemirror search simulate CTRL+F keys with javascript

Tags: javascript, codemirror, key-events

I'm trying to open the codemirror search dialog (normally activated by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
by pressing a button:

I tried to use

```
window.find()
```

but it does not open the dialog, it only highlights the text in the editor...

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cb1fd72k/)**

Comment: using window.find will poke the view html, not the model text content, which is only exposed via the API, so you need to  use the codemirror API. there are also search plugins to peruse/modify. it's also under [F3]...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to simulate the actual key press. Rather, simply run CodeMirror's find command using `execCommand`, as in http://jsfiddle.net/cb1fd72k/1/

Comment: ok now I added also buttons for "findNext", "findPrev", but it does not work for "replace" and "replaceAll".. why?